# C#, Having an issue with two buttons starting one method

Tags: c#, winforms, button

If you're from the USA, and you've ever been to a Cracker Barrel, then you've probably played the board game where you have to jump pegs until you only have one left. It's similar to Chinese checkers, with just a pyramid, or a triangle.

I have a form that makes the buttons and adds them to the form, and I have a "TheBoard" class that has all of the rules for how jumping works on the form.  In my form, I also have a button clicker method that needs to run all of this.

I seem to have hit a brick wall.  I can't figure out the logic behind getting it to accept a second click, in order to move through the whole `if` statements in the board class.  My parameter for the move method in the board class takes an `int x`, which is the button you click on as a parameter.  I feel like I'm missing the second half of the move. How do I get my move method to register two button clicks (the starting location of the peg and the end location of the peg)?

Code for form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button[] btn = new Button[15];
    private TheBoard myboard = new TheBoard();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int buttonsPerRow = 1;
        int index = 0;

        while (index < btn.Length)
        {
            int increment = this.Width / (buttonsPerRow + 1);

            for (int j = 1; j <= buttonsPerRow; j++)
            {
                btn[index] = new Button
                {
                    //other style elements of the button
                    Name = "btn" + index
                } 


                btn[index].Click += new EventHandler(this.My_Click);
                Controls.Add(btn[index]);

                index++;
            }

            buttonsPerRow++;
        }
    }

    private void My_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    myboard.getValues();
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    string bName = b.Name;
    // Now pull off the btn
    string num = bName.Substring(3, bName.Length - 3);
    // Parsing the number to an int
    int x = Int32.Parse(num);
    myboard.move(x);

    int[] color = myboard.getValues();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        color = myboard.getValues();
        if (color[i] == TheBoard.hasPeg)
        {
            btn[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        }
        else
            btn[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }//for



    }
}
```

Code for TheBoard class:

```
class TheBoard
{
  static public int hasPeg = 100;
    static public int noPeg = 50;
    private int[] board;
    private int firstMove; //1st click

    public TheBoard()
    {
        board = new int[15];
        board[0] = noPeg;
        for(int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
        {
            board[i] = hasPeg;
        }
        firstMove = -1; //giving last move a location, starting it at the beginning
    }

    public int move(int x)
    {
        if(firstMove == -1)
        {
            firstMove = x;
            return 0;
        }
        // blank at 0


        // if you click a blank your 1st move
        if (firstMove == noPeg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You cant move if there isn't a peg.");
            return 666;
        }


        // first---------------------------------------middle-----------------------end
        if (firstMove == 1 && board[0] == hasPeg && board[3] == hasPeg && board[6] == noPeg)
        {
            RemovePeg(board[0], board[3], board[6]);
            return 0;
        }
        if (firstMove == 1 && board[0] == hasPeg && board[2] == hasPeg && board[4] == noPeg)
        {
            RemovePeg(board[0], board[2], board[4]);
            return 0;
        }
        //etc for remaining firstMove possibilities

        firstMove = -1;
        return 5;
    }

    private int RemovePeg(int first, int second, int goal) {
        board[goal] = hasPeg;
        board[first] = noPeg;
        board[second] = noPeg;
        return 0;
    }

    public int[] getValues()
    {
        return board;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should assign "onclick" event in your buttons!

Comment: I'm a novice, so I'm not really sure what you mean..  In the for loop that creates each button or in the my_Click in form1?

Answer (score 0):

I looked over the code and I think I understand your problem; you can select the starting peg but you don't have a way to select where it should go. With minimal edit to your code, I would store the first button click in a global variable and then the second button click knows that it is the second and initiates the board move with the two pieces of information (and resets the global variable).

Comment: So I need to have 2 parameters in my move method, or the only parameter that needs to be in there is the 2nd click?

Comment: I would have two. `From` and `To`. The move method wouldn't be called until the second click.

Comment: can I just use a flag then to see if its the first or second click?  Like a count = 0 then it does the first click, then set count to 1, and have a statement that runs the move method based off of the input from the 2 clicks?

Comment: Yes, that sounds good. I would store `count=0` and then when a button is pressed check `if (count==0) {count= index of button;}else{move(count,new index); count =0;}`